# The permutation that minimizes the sum of floor(a_i / i)

Tags: optimization, permutations, ceiling-and-floor-functions, discrete-optimization

Given $n$, what is the permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ that minimizes

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left\lfloor \dfrac {a_i}{i} \right\rfloor$$

where $a_i$ denotes the $i$th element of the permutation.

Comment: I guess it is $(n, n - 1, \dots, 1)$

Comment: @Taladris I'm not getting your ideas. The question had been about the sum of floor of the quotient.

Comment: when $n=3$ the value of $(3, 2, 1)$ is $4$, but a minimum value of $2$ can be achieved by $(1, 3, 2)$.

Comment: I purpose the minimum achieve at a(i)={1,2,3,...k-1,n,k,....n-1} by move n to position k. And I guess k~sqrt(n+1) with some floor function etc. Looks like a good MO problem.

Comment: For $n\in\{1,\dots,100\}$, the minimum is $1+\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$.